# Does ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64 supports Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320

Tags: system-installation

Can I use ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64  in order to install ubuntu on my laptop having Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320 processor

Comment: Your processor is supported other bits of your laptop may not be create a USB and try without installing.  If all goes well install, if not ask another question about what isn't working before you commit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  The i5 is a 64 bit capable processor and runs Ubuntu 64 bit very well.  We have several in the office all working perfectly.